# Developing Features for Application and Communicating Changes

Tags: git, svn, web-applications, communication

I'm maintaining and regularly developing features for a web application used at a company.

I'm currently using SVN to keep track of my changes. I'm okay with using Git or something else.

My goal is as follows: Have a page on the web application that shows commits, their descriptions, and, optionally, diffs on the codebase. This way, I don't necessarily have to push out emails communicating changes/bugfixes.

Is there an easy way to do this via Git or SVN?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it completely, you want to show the commits on your own web app?

Comment: this is possible with any modern version control system. SVN and git will work.